# JPA Select Item by ForeginKey

Tags: sql, database, spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I want to fetch data form database using Springs CrudRepository

The code I have is:

Region:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = NAME)
data class Region(
        @Id @GeneratedValue val id: Long,
        val name: String,
        val lat: Double,
        val lon: Double,
        @CollectionTable(name = "RegionAlternateName", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")])
        @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @Column(name = "name")
        val alternateNames: List<String>
) {
    companion object {
        const val NAME = "Region"
    }
}
```

SubRegion:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = NAME)
@NamedQueries(
        NamedQuery(name = "Region.findByRegionId", query = "SELECT e FROM SubRegion e WHERE (e.region.id) =:regionId")
)
data class SubRegion(
        @Id @GeneratedValue val id: Long,
        val lat: Double,
        val lon: Double,
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn(name = "id") val region: Region
) {
    companion object {
        const val NAME = "SubRegion"
    }
}
```

SubRegionRepository:

```
@Repository
interface SubRegionRepository : CrudRepository<SubRegion, Long> {
    fun findByRegionId(regionId: Long): SubRegion?
}
```

But when I use method 
`subRegionRepository.findByRegionId(3)`
I receive SubRegion with id = 3, not "Some" Subregion that belongs to Region with id = 3

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the SQL that is generated?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli where I can find it?

Comment: you can set the logger org.hibernate.SQL to DEBUG.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli select subregion0_.id as id1_1_, subregion0_.subregion_id as subregion2_1_ from subregion subregion0_ where subregion0_.id=?